# Invalid argument/option - '|'

Tags: python

When trying to run the tasklist command with grep by using subprocess:

```
command = ("tasklist | grep edpa.exe | gawk \"{ print $2 }\"")
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = p.communicate(timeout=600)[0]
print(text)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '|'.
Type "TASKLIST /?" for usage.
```

It works fine when i run the command directly from cmd, but when using subprocess something goes wrong.
How can it be fixed? I need to use the output of the command so i can not use `os.system`
.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Use the `shell=True` option of the Popen(); this will pass it through the shell, which is the part that interprets things like the `|`
- Just run `tasklist` in the Popen(), then do the processing in Python rather than invoking grep and awk

Of the two, the latter is probably the better approach in this particular instance, since these grep and awk commands are easily translated into Python.

Your linters may also complain that `shell=True` is prone to security issues, although this particular usage would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of `shell=True`, `subprocess` runs a *single* subprocess. In other words, you are passing `|` and `grep` etc as arguments to `tasklist`.

The simplest fix is to add `shell=True`; but a much better fix is to do the trivial text processing in Python instead. This also coincidentally gets rid of the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

```py
for line in subprocess.check_output(['tasklist'], timeout=600).splitlines():
    if 'edpa.exe' in line:
        text = line.split()[1]
        print(text)
```

I have assumed you really want to match `edpa.exe` literally, anywhere in the output line; your regex would match `edpa` followed by any character followed by `exe`. The code could be improved by doing the `split` first and then look for the search string only in the process name field (if that is indeed your intent).

Perhaps notice also how you generally want to avoid the low-level `Popen` whenever you can use one of the higher-level functions.

Comment: Really you'd want to do the `.split()` first, then match "edpa.exe" more specifically in the relevant column, so it doesn't match "edpa.exe" as anything other than the full name of the executable

Comment: Sure; many things could be improved in the OP's code, but I didn't want to second-guess what the output looks like on their OS or what exactly they _actually_ want.